# How can I solve this IOException?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get a user token from a url but I keep getting an `IOException`:

> (W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: url)

I have  tried to run the API from postman, and that seems to work. The request method is `GET`:

```java
private class userlogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
  @Override
  public void onPreExecute() {
      progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(userLogin.this);
      progressDialog.setMessage("please wait.........");
      progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
      progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
      progressDialog.setTitle("Logging in");
      progressDialog.show();
  }

  @Override
  public String doInBackground(String... para) {

      try {
          URL url = new URL(webconfigs.LOGIN_URL);
          Map<String, String> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
          params.put("grant_type", "password");
          params.put("username", para[0]);
          params.put("password", para[1]);
          utility.updateSharedPreference(userLogin.this, "Username", para[0]);
          utility.updateSharedPreference(getApplicationContext(), "Password", para[1]);
          //just to check if it is sored in the shared prefrence
          utility.fetchFromSharedPreference(getApplicationContext(), "Username");
          utility.fetchFromSharedPreference(getApplicationContext(), "Password");
          Log.e(">>Username>>", para[0]);
          Log.e(">>Password>>", para[1]);


          StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
          for (Map.Entry<String, String> param : params.entrySet()) {

              if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
              postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
              postData.append('=');
              postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
          }
          String urlparameters = postData.toString();
          HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          conn.setConnectTimeout(3000);
          conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
          conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", webconfigs.CONTENT_TYPE);
          conn.setDoOutput(true);
          //connect  the url
          conn.connect();
          //conn.setDoOutput(true);
          OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
          writer.write(urlparameters);
          writer.flush();
          //create our buffered reader to read from the input stream reader
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
          StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();

          //checking the status of the response code
          Integer resposeCode =  conn.getResponseCode();
          String responsecode1 = resposeCode.toString();
          Log.e("the respose code is :", responsecode1);
          String line;
          String result= "";
          // consume the response and read it line by line as
          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             st.append(line);

          }
          reader.close();
          writer.close();
          result = st.toString();
          return result;


      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

        return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);

      Log.e(">>>>LOGINSERVERRESPONSE", ">>>>>" + result);
      progressDialog.dismiss();
      try {
          JSONObject results = new JSONObject(result);
          String token = results.getString("access_token");
          if (token != null) {
              String accessToken = results.getString("access_token");
              String tokenType = results.getString("token_type");
              String dateIssued = results.getString(".issued");
              String expiryDate = results.getString(".expires_in");
          }

      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
      startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), drawerLayout.class));
  }

}
```

Comment: check your webservice url

Comment: it is working fine

Answer (score -1):

the problem with using the asynchtask is that when the credentials that are used are wrong the problem will exist ,incase that happens,use a different user from the database